# Cannot achieve 1000 concurrent function requests with Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run an RNA-Seq application with Google Cloud Functions. To run this application I need to be able to have over 800 functions running concurrently. This has been achieved using AWS Lambda, but I have not been able to do this on Google Cloud Functions.

When I attempt to run hundreds of basic HTTP requests with the default HTTP trigger, I start getting tons of 500 errors:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

If I check the logs for my function, I see no error messages! The cloud console makes it seem like everything is perfect even though my requests are failing.

How should I got about diagnosing this problem? It looks like it's something wrong on Google's end, as my code works fine when requests do go through. Does Google limit the amount of HTTP requests you can make?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I never try a such load test. However, with Cloud Run, when the scale up is too slow compare to the traffic, the HTTP error code is 529 and not 500. It should be the same on Cloud Function (it's the same underlying infrastructure). Are you sure that you don't require external resource that crash your Function? Like SQL database connexion or something like this? Anyway, did you try Cloud Run for processing several query on the same instance? You can reduce the cost and the number of concurrent instances, and solve your problem like this!

Comment: All my test function does is sleep for 10 seconds and returns a message from the request. It basically just hello world with some sleeping. There are no databases, external services or anything.

Answer (score 1):

The scaling limit for HTTP type functions is different than background functions.  Please read the documentation about [scalability](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#scalability) to be clear on the limits.

For background functions, it will scale gradually up to 1000 current invocations.  Since you're writing an HTTP function, this does not apply.

For HTTP functions, note that rates are limited by the amount of outbound network bandwidth generated by the function (among other things).  You will have to take a close look at what your function is actually doing to figure out if it's exceeding the documented rate limits.

If you can limit what the function is doing internally to meet the scalability limits, one thing you can try is to shard your functions.  Instead of one HTTP function, create two, and split traffic between them.  The stated limits are *per-function* (not per-project), so you should be able to handle more load that way.

Comment: I don’t think I should be hitting any limits. All my test function does is sleep for 10 seconds and returns a message I send it. It does almost nothing. 

It uses an HTTP trigger so I shouldn’t have to worry about the limitations for background functions.